# Magento theme not displaying all search results

Tags: php, magento, search

Search function is working fine, the title shows "511 products found", it shows the correct number of products returned by search function, but in the grid below this title it only shows one product and layout breaks after showing title of first product. The search results page uses 2-col template and this template is working fine on category pages but in search results its only showing one product.

Please help me resolve this issue

Theme is: ARW sebian

Magento version: 1.9

Site URL `http://armafix.juvenatemediatest.co.uk`

Comment: uncomment `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  code in your index.php, and then reload the search result page, it will show the error